# What is the purpose of silence.mp3 file in a Shopify store?

Tags: shopify, gtmetrix

Every time I analyze a Shopify store in GTmetrix and look at the waterfall, where you can see all the data behavior when loading, I always find a silence.mp3. I have analyzed a dozen Shopify stores and it's always there.

an example:
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0070/3666/5911/files/silence.mp3?1304

you can check a real store:
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/petmania.shop/mb6KTPjP/

There is always a gap (I guess javascript parsing) before this file. Most likely it is always located at the end of the waterfall. But I can't really understand its purpose. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Without knowing anything else, it’s probably part of some broader browser fingerprinting technology they’re running. Likely for security, but could also be for ad tracking, etc.

Comment: If this file is annoying you by any way I think the best option is to contact Shopify's support for a reliable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking and making some R&D it found the file is added in an iframe by the Shopify App called "SuperLemon App"
[image]

[image]